# Set Github repo so people can see it but cannot clone it?

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to share a Github repo so people can view it but not download/clone it? I would like someone to see a complete project that I built but not have the ability to clone.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If they can see your code on GitHub, a truly devoted copier could just copy-paste all the files' contents. If you're worried people will ruin your source project, just don't accept pull requests when they come in.

Comment: If someone REALLY wanted to copy-paste.... yes it would work. I'm just trying to make it more difficult. I guess it is not possible?

Comment: If you don't want people to have your code, you either need a private repository or no repository at all.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I am just asking if it is possible. What if you wanted to show someone a project you built but didn't want them to be able to copy the entire source code? My solution is to share on Github for a half hour. They cannot  copy it all by then... PS they don't want to i'm sure... I'm just asking if its possible. Yes or no is fine here. Why I want to do it... who really cares...

Comment: The short version is no, it's not possible, but for future reference, if you give some context with your question, people might be able to help you more. I wasn't sure if your circumstances might've helped me answer.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted a simple answer. Seems like if you get too long winded people say "Just ask the question"... but I do thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand what you are saying. I am just asking if it is possible

It isn't possible.

> What if you wanted to show someone a project you built but didn't want them to be able to copy the entire source code?

Like the comments have hinted upon, how could you prevent someone from copying all the code, if they can just transcribe everything to a file? It's not even that hard to scrape the HTML page and automate the whole thing. Worst case scenario someone could just write it down.

Comment: What if with no warning you shared a github that could not be cloned. Do you think they would have the scraper ready and the content scraped within 30 minutes? Possible yes... likely no. Is it crazy to ask the question.... Is it possible to make a Github repo un-clonable? ... it's a simple question. If you can't do it fine. Just say no. Who cares...

Comment: I just said no. it isn't possible, the feature is not there.

Comment: And I thank you for the answer. Other people seem hell bent on letting me know that if someone wants to copy-paste they can do that.... no duh they can. I just don't want to make it super easy. No biggie.

Comment: Regardless, your question title is about cloning, and that feature could be there. Like everyone said, you can still "copy" the contents but the `git clone` could potentially be disabled.

Comment: How can git clone be disabled @bitoiu

Comment: It can't, mate. I've answered it can't be done. It's not possible. I said the feature "as useless as it was" could be there. In the sense, GitHub could decide to do it.